# Copying existing columns between DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

having a DataFrame with e.g. 10 columns (a, b, c...) and another smaller one with just let's say 3 of them (d, f, h), what is the 'best' way to copy the columns from the second DataFrame to the first?

The below seems to do the trick but I'm wondering if I should use join, merge or something else instead (for better performance/cleaner code)?

```
dfOutput = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'])
melted = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],columns=['d','h','i'])

dfOutput[melted.columns] = melted[melted.columns]
```

Comment: can you please post a sample dataframe and expected output? thank you . BDW `pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)` brings both dataframe together horizontally.

Comment: pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=0) seems to do the trick, indeed. If df1 and df2 both have data for the same column, those get appended. I'd like to always replace the data from dfOutput by the melted values instead, though

Comment: check the two scenarios I have provided in the answer, i think you are looking for senario at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need [`df.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`df.reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
melted.merge(dfOutput,on=['d','h','i'],how='left').reindex(dfOutput.columns,axis=1)

    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j
0   NaN NaN NaN 1   NaN NaN NaN 2   3   NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN 4   NaN NaN NaN 5   6   NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN 7   NaN NaN NaN 8   9   NaN
```

you can reassign this to the first dataframe :

```
dfOutput = melted.merge(dfOutput,on=['d','h','i'],how='left').reindex(dfOutput.columns,axis=1)
```

**Scenario 2** : If you already have data in certain columns , use `dfOutput.update(melted)` to update the first dataframe with the second:

For example:

dfOutput:

```
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j
0   NaN NaN NaN 1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN 2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN 3   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

melted:

```
    d   h   i
0   5   6   7
1   4   8   6
2   7   4   9

>>dfOutput.update(melted)
>>dfOutput

    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j
0   NaN NaN NaN 5   NaN NaN NaN 6   7   NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN 4   NaN NaN NaN 8   6   NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN 7   NaN NaN NaN 4   9   NaN
```